# "Property Boss" runs into errors on Wine, is there a way to get it to work without errors?

Tags: wine

I have a server running Ubuntu 12.04 and I have installed WINE to test if I can run a Windows program called Property Boss.

Property Boss does not support any Linux system so I'm on my own.

The install went well with no errors popping up, but when I tried to open the GUI I received some script errors. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

[image: 1st error]

[image: 2nd error]

[image: 3rd error]

Comment: I want your screen shot app

Comment: @Nade those aren't "screenshots" those are camera pictures of what the system says on the screen, those aren't "screenshots" in the sense that a program is taking those pictures, it's someone with a camera doing that.

Comment: Yep, it's a phone camera

Comment: @ThomasW. Ya that was the joke

Answer (score 2):

Not every program works with Wine.  Wine is not designed to work flawlessly with every program, and there are programs that just won't work with Wine at all.

As there is no entry in the Wine App Database about this program, it's impossible to say whether this will actually work with Wine or not, however judging by the runtime errors you're running into, I would say it just doesn't work with Wine.